# Is there a way to write $1/(x-y) = f(x) g(y)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, rational-functions

For $x>0$ and $y>0$, do there exist some single-variable functions $f$ and $g$ for which
$$
\frac{1}{x-y} = f(x) g(y) \ ?
$$

Comment: I don't believe so.  It is not what we call "separable".  Many functions don't have that property; the ones that do are interesting and we tend to work with those more when we can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't.  Let $d=x-y$.  Then $$\frac1d = f(x)g(x-d).$$

Fix $x$ and let $y$ approach $x$ so that $d$ approaches zero.  The left side goes to infinity.  On the right side, the factor $f(x)$ is constant.  For the product to go to infinity, we must have $$\lim_{d\to 0} g(x-d) = \infty.$$

But this last equation holds for *any* fixed value of $x$.  This is impossible.

The argument for $\frac1{x+y}$ will be essentially the same.